# can we keep the variable as final in java

Tags: java, spring

I am reading a file path from spring properties file as shown below and that is mapped into a java class

```
#file path
file.path =/root/ms_data/file/
```

and it is mapped into java class like this

```
@Value("${file.path}")
    private String fileDataPath;
```

Please advise can I keep it as final I mean like this as shown below in which I kept fileDataPath as the final one

```
@Value("${file.path}")
private final String fileDataPath;
```

Comment: Why you need final ? may be you need static instead .

Comment: @AbinashGhosh spring and `static` does not go well together and I can't see a reason why it should be used here

Comment: @Lino may be this class for reading  properties file,  so using static help to use member statically from class , since object of this class may not use anywhere

Comment: @AbinashGhosh That is a rather bad use of spring then, you should always work with components and inject them where you need to, else you will have lots of unknown static dependencies to a class and testing will give you nightmares. See also [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/364496/are-spring-beans-declared-as-static-a-poor-design-choice)

Answer (score 6):

You can use constructor injection for this:

```
public class YourClass {
    private final String fileDataPath;

    public YourClass(@Value("${file.path}") String fileDataPath) {
        this.fileDataPath = fileDataPath;
    }
}
```

For more on constructor injection, I suggest reading through the following questions, they go into a lot more detail than I ever could:

- [Explain why constructor inject is better than other options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21218868/5515060)
- [When to use constructor injection in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27132348/5515060)
- [Spring @Autowire on Properties vs Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620000/spring-autowire-on-properties-vs-constructor)
- [Setter DI vs. Constructor DI in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779509/setter-di-vs-constructor-di-in-spring)

Comment: This is only one of the many valuable advantages of constructor injection!